# EF 6 Navigation property between two objects of the same type

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a EF db model called Booking

```
public class Booking
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // some other properties...
}
```

I need to be able to link two different bookings together, how can create a navigation property that gives me a link between each booking?

E.g, Booking A needs a navigation property to Booking B and vice versa, Booking B needs a navigation property to Booking A.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it only a one to one relation or do you also require more than two to be linked?

Comment: only a one to one relationship

Comment: This will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398417/entity-framework-code-first-tree-model you only need a reference property and foreign key

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do like another navigation property:

```
public class Booking
{
    // Your current code and... 

    // If you want One to One:
    public virtual Booking RelatedBooking { get; set; }
    // but if it's One to Many:
    public virtual ICollection<Booking> RelaitedBookings { get; set; }
}
```

I hope it helps.